# "n/a" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, abbreviation

How would one say `n/a` (not applicable) in German? The only guesses I can come up with are `fehlend`or `nicht verfügbar`, but they don't have the exact meaning of n/a. Also, how would you abbreviate the equivalent of `n/a` in German?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several possiblities:

If you want to express, that data is missing, you should use

> nicht verfügbar (n.v.)

If you want to express, that a data point can't be / isn't defined, you should use

> nicht definiert (n.d.)

But in general, `n/a` is also used in German.

Comment: it should be added that "not applicable" would have a literal translation of "nicht zutreffend", which again is sometimes used as a synonym for "falsch" (as in "incorrect").

Comment: @syneticon-dj More literal would be `nicht anwendbar`, but this is misleading in cases of data just missing.

Comment: ＋１  N/A also being used in German.

Answer (score 4):

We used to simply type   ./.  into the relevant column, and that was generally understood as n/a

Comment: Who is "we", and in which context did this happen?

Comment: Nur die Frage, wie man es abkürzen kann, ist damit beantwortet, nicht wie man es sagt.

Comment: Well, 'we' is we in the office.

And the full phrase woud be 'Nicht zutreffend' but you can't abbreviate that, hence the ./.

Answer (score 3):

*Duden-Oxford – Großwörterbuch Englisch,* 3rd edition (2005) gives two translations for the abbreviation n/a.

1) For the meaning “not available”: n. bek.

2) For the meaning “not applicable”: entf.

Comment: "nicht bekannt", "entfällt"